# Huggingface pretrained model's tokenizer and model objects have different maximum input length

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, sentence-transformers

I'm using ***symanto/sn-xlm-roberta-base-snli-mnli-anli-xnli*** pretrained model from huggingface. My task requires to use it on pretty large texts, so it's essential to know maximum input length.

The following code is supposed to load pretrained model and its tokenizer:

```
encoding_model_name = "symanto/sn-xlm-roberta-base-snli-mnli-anli-xnli"
encoding_tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(encoding_model_name)
encoding_model = SentenceTransformer(encoding_model_name)
```

So, when I print info about them:

```
encoding_tokenizer
encoding_model
```

I'm getting:

```
PreTrainedTokenizerFast(name_or_path='symanto/sn-xlm-roberta-base-snli-mnli-anli-xnli', vocab_size=250002, model_max_len=512, is_fast=True, padding_side='right', truncation_side='right', special_tokens={'bos_token': '<s>', 'eos_token': '</s>', 'unk_token': '<unk>', 'sep_token': '</s>', 'pad_token': '<pad>', 'cls_token': '<s>', 'mask_token': AddedToken("<mask>", rstrip=False, lstrip=True, single_word=False, normalized=False)})
```

```
SentenceTransformer(
  (0): Transformer({'max_seq_length': 128, 'do_lower_case': False}) with Transformer model: XLMRobertaModel 
  (1): Pooling({'word_embedding_dimension': 768, 'pooling_mode_cls_token': False, 'pooling_mode_mean_tokens': True, 'pooling_mode_max_tokens': False, 'pooling_mode_mean_sqrt_len_tokens': False})
)
```

As you can see, **model_max_len=512** parameter in tokenizer doesn't match **max_seq_length=128** parameter in model

How can I figure out which one is true? Or, probably, if they somehow respond to different features, how I can check maximum input length for my model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using a SentenceTransformer and load it to the SentenceTransformer class, it will truncate your input at 128 tokens as stated by the [documentation](https://www.sbert.net/docs/package_reference/SentenceTransformer.html#sentence_transformers.SentenceTransformer.max_seq_length) (the relevant code is [here](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/b90970c190658f7588c86e8a3fb9cc400716ecd4/sentence_transformers/models/Transformer.py#L113)):

> property max_seq_length
> Property to get the maximal input sequence length for the model. Longer inputs will be truncated.

You can also check this by yourself:

```py
fifty = model.encode(["This "*50], convert_to_tensor=True)
two_hundered = model.encode(["This "*200], convert_to_tensor=True)
four_hundered = model.encode(["This "*400], convert_to_tensor=True)

print(torch.allclose(fifty, two_hundered))
print(torch.allclose(two_hundered,four_hundered))
```

Output:

```py
False
True
```

The underlying model (xlm-roberta-base) is able to handle sequences with up to 512 tokens, but I assume [Symanto](https://huggingface.co/symanto) limited it to 128 because they also used this limit during training (i.e. the embeddings might be not good for sequences longer than 128 tokens).

Answer (score 0):

Model_max_length is the maximum length of positional embedding the model can take. To check this, do
`print(model.config)`
you'll see `"max_position_embeddings": 512` along with other configs.

> how I can check the maximum input length for my model?

You can pass the max_length(as much as your model can take) when you're encoding the text sequences:
`tokenizer.encode(txt, max_length=512)`